# select rows by date with Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a csv-File (Columns: Date, Price, x, y, z), frow which I would like to read only the rows that fall into a certain time period. I tried this:

```
...
abc1 = pandas.read_csv(filesource1, parse_dates=['Date'])
abc2 = abc1.price

startDate = datetime(2014,8,1)
endDate = datetime(2018,3,1)
daterange = pandas.date_range(startDate,endDate)

abc3 = abc2[daterange]
print (abc3.head())
```

This gives me a list, where only the date is included and price is 'NaN'. How would this be done right?

Comment: Is it ok to read in the entire file and then slice the data frame so that you only keep the rows with certain date values? Or is there a reason (perhaps the file is extremely large or you need to do the extremely quickly) that you want to only read certain lines?

Comment: Can you also post your CSV?

Comment: yes, it is ok to read the whole file and then process only the selected date-range.

Comment: the file is nothing special. Example:  02/11/2001,23:00,1048.3,1055.2,1043.8,1050.9,82796,310272 ---- date, time (always the same), price....

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this additions:

```
abc1 = pandas.read_csv(filesource1, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'], usecols=['Date', 'Price'])
```